# Estimating vertical asymptotes via numerical integration

Tags: c, precision, ode, numerical-integration, approximation

I am integrating a differential equation with Runge-Kutta 2 method in order to obtain an approximate solution y_n(t), where n is a varying initial parameter. Then, for a sample of n's in a chosen range I want to find the first root of y_n(t) by recording the first change of sign: the result is a function R(n) that has a vertical asymptote at some value of n, where R(n) is the first root of y_n(t).

My question is then: how can I estimate the value of the vertical asymptote?

---

I do not see any way of doing that for the moment. I have thought about checking that for small changes of n the value of R(n) should not change too much at each step, but that is not true especially if there is an exponential or worse growth. I have also thought about just choosing an "upper bound", meaning that if R(n) is greater than some limit then I could approximate the vertical asymptote by that value of n, but I do not like this solution because I have no control over the error I am making.

Are there any more clever ideas?

---

Any comment or answer is much appreciated and let me know if I can explain myself clearer!

Comment: I guess your question might be more relevant to https://math.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Runge–Kutta methods use polynomials to approximate a function; why not use Newton's method?

Comment: @Neil I could also use Newton’s Method, but the problem remains that I do not know how to estimate the vertical asymptote position.

Comment: @Fryz I don’t think so, this is not a question about the math of the problem but rather about how to implement a code in order to detect a mathematical property of a numerically integrated solution to an ODE.

Comment: I thought you were using RK4, but if you're just using 2, there is no reason not to solve it exactly. Here's [a link that has code](https://lpsa.swarthmore.edu/NumInt/NumIntSecond.html).